# Modify a vector by changing its pointer doesn't work in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, stl

Below is the snippet, I want to point the `first` variable to the `second` variable without copying the vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> second (4,100);
void modify(std::vector<int>* i) {
  i = &second;
}
int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> first;                                // empty vector of ints
  modify(&first);
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = first.begin(); it != first.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

The output is empty, while I expected the output to be `100 100 100 100`.

Does anyone have ideas about why can't I modify the vector like this?

Comment: Can you "modify" an `int` by "changing its pointer" in the same way? Maybe it has nothing to do with vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the pointer by value.  That means anything you change the pointer to point to in the function will not be seen outside the function.  What you need to do is pass the pointer by reference if you want to see the changes in the call site.  This won't work in this case though since

```
modify(&first);
```

is a rvalue pointer and cannot be bound to a non const lvalue reference.

All of this though is not needed.  We can just change the function to take a reference like

```
void modify(std::vector<int>& i) {
  i = second;
}
```

and then `modify(&first);` becomes `modify(first);` and now the changes will be reflected in `main()`.

Comment: Thanks! Is this copy-by-value or copy-by-reference?

Comment: @HanfeiSun My suggest is to pass by reference instead of by pointer by value.

Comment: @HanfeiSun its called pass by reference. Copies are always "by value" if you want to call it like that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you wanted this instead:

```
void modify(std::vector<int>* i) {
  *i = second;
}
```

it is "old" way to modify value through parameter and it may have an issue:

```
void modify(std::vector<int>* i) {
  if( !i ) {
      // what should I do?
      throw std::runtime_exception( "cannot modify vector through nullptr" );
  }
  *i = second;
}
```

this additional check can be avoided using reference instead which also would make your intention clearer to the reader of the code, unless you really want to pass `nullptr` sometimes for some reason (tell function not to change value, but do something else for example).